# Photoshop - Blur Effect?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photo-editing, effects, blur

[image: BLUR EFFECT]

How did he do that? I can not find the path to that artwork.

Comment: The only 'blur' here is in the background, and I presume you are not asking about that... Look at the stripes coming from the head: you can see his eye stretched all out. It most certainly is not a stock Photoshop effect.

Answer (score 3):

There is no blur involved, it's all Warping.

1. Start with an appropriate image. Here is one I like :)

[image: it's Jackie!]

(from http://www.serialoptimist.com/admin/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/Images-of-Jackie-Chan.jpeg)

2. Make sure you have a free-standing Jackie - make a copy of him without the background. This will be necessary later on, because some of the sweeps go behind the image.
3. The warping effect works best with a single *extremely thin* sliver of pixels, ideally only 1 pixel wide or high. Make a selection in the image that is at least as high as the target swipe is going to be, and in a good orientation (either horizontally or vertically).

[image: I'll have a slice of Jackie]

4. Copy, and paste it again to get it on a layer of its own. Now expand this to the left and right, using a simple Free Transform. You'll end up with a swath of color stripes:

[image: s-hwooosh!!]

5. Use Warp to maneuver this into position. Make the left edge taper off "in the distance", and make sure the right edge fits more or less nicely onto the position you copied it from. Then move the layer with Jacky on top.

[image: kay-yaaah!!]

6. We have a bit more movement here, so repeat for other moving elements: his foot and his arm. To make the effect go 'under' his foot, I also copied that onto a layer of its own.

[image: haa-iiii]

7. That original orange background is a bit boring. Here is a final image with some heavily blurred flames (just to have *some* blur in the image).

[image: ker-powww!!]

8. Add an appropriate quote to finish it off.

[image: Jackie's background]

Comment: @MarieDrache: you're welcome! After guessing how it may have been done, it was also fun to find out how to actually replicate it. If my post helped you out, you can [accept this](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) by clicking the large "check" mark. This shows others with a similar question that this one has an answer that works.